# Triple cross product formula using multilinear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, multilinear-algebra, cross-product, exterior-algebra

Trying to compute the formula for the triple cross product
$$ a \times (b \times c) = \langle c, a\rangle b - \langle b, a \rangle c $$
using wedge, hodge star and contraction operations I get
\begin{align}a \times (b \times c) &= *(a \wedge *(b \wedge c)) = \\
&= i_a(b \wedge c) =\\
&= \langle a, b \rangle c - \langle a, c\rangle b
\end{align}
which is the opposite of the currect result. Where is the error?

---

The formulas I used are

- $ a \times b = *(a \wedge b)$;
- $ i_x(v) = \langle v, x \rangle$ for $x, y$ 1-vectors and $i_x(v \wedge a) = i_x(v) a - v \wedge i_x(a)$ when $a$ is a $k\geq 1$-vector;
- $i_x(a) = *(x \wedge *(a))$.

---

Edit.

Apparently the [currect identity](https://mathoverflow.net/a/165524) is

$$*(v \wedge w) = i_w(* v)$$

and using the fact that $*^2 = 1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the derivation would be

\begin{align}a \times (b \times c) &= *(a \wedge *(b \wedge c)) = \\
&= (-1)^{1 \cdot 1} *(*(b \wedge c) \wedge a) = \\
&= - i_a(*^2(b \wedge c)) = \\
&= - i_a(b \wedge c) = \\
&= - \langle a, b \rangle c + \langle a, c\rangle b
\end{align}

Comment: Indeed, edited, thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I think the mistake is that the dual of the dual in dimension 3, is -1 ($*\circ * = (-1)\text{id}$).</s> E.g. I believe you should have

$i_x(a) = -(*(x\wedge *(a)))$.

Note: the original point is wrong since I believed that $*(a) \leftrightarrow Ia$ in geometric algebra. The final result is correct, though, since it does map directly onto GA.

Comment: For a $k$-vector in an $n$-dimensional vector space the double dual satisfies $**(\alpha) = (-1)^{k(n-k)} \alpha$, hence if $n$ is odd then the double dual is $\operatorname{id}$, right? Anyway why the $-1$ in the formula for the inner product?

Comment: Oh, but on the second half you are right; if $e_1, e_2, e_3$ is an orthonormal positive oriented basis of a 3-dimensional space then $i_{e_1}(e_1 \wedge e_2) = e_2$ while $*(e_1 \wedge *(e_1 \wedge e_2)) = *(e_1 \wedge e_3) = - e_2$. Do you know the correct general formula for the interior product in terms of Hodge dual?

Comment: Indeed! I'm not too familiar with the exterior algebra formalism (I use the geometric algebra one) which is why I screwed up there, but the proofs are (mostly) one-to-one in some sense. Pardon any mistakes here, but the idea is that we define the dual as the operation such that $x\wedge *(a) = i_x(a)\omega$ where $\omega$ is the preferred $n$-vector of the space, for two vectors $a, x$ of the same dimension. Therefore $*(x\wedge *(a)) = *(i_x(a) \omega) = *(\omega)(i_x(a))$. I'm not sure what the dual of the preferred $n$-vector is in general, but I suspect it is $\pm 1$ depending on sign.

Comment: This is by noting that $i_x(a)$ is scalar for $a, x$ of the same dimension. E.g. if it's anything like GA, the sign would be $(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}$.

Comment: I made some (ugly) explicit calculations and found out that $i_x(a) = (-1)^{(n-k) + k(n-k)} *(x \wedge (*a)) = (-1)^{k(n-k)} *((*a) \wedge x) = ***((*a) \wedge x)$, maybe there is a simple proof of this equality without using a basis. The property(or definition) $x\wedge *(a) = i_x(a)\omega$ is quite interesting, but this gives only the case when $a$ is a $1$-vector, hence $(k+1)(n-k)$ is even; it would be helpful to generalize it for vectors of different dimensions.

Comment: So, this is generally the definition where we allow $a, x$ to be arbitrary $k$-vectors (not just 1-vectors, so long as both $a, x$ have the same dimension); but there are several possible definitions. The above $(-1)^{n-k + k(n-k)}$ is very close to the case in GA, so I suspect that is correct.